# Can I just use Page_Load and no button click of the web form?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a `aspx` web form which has a set of controls and a submit button.

- In the `Page_Load` event of the page, I fill the controls with data.
- In the button click event, I have to save the form data in the database and redirect to another page using `Response.Redirect`.

During the testing I have found out that the `Page_Load event` is also called when a button is clicked. Can I use only the `Page_Load` event to fill the control and save the data, and not use the button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use just `Page_Load` with `IsPostBack` flag to add code that should go in the Button click event IF you are absolutely sure there is only one control that will cause the postback.

If there are multiple controls that could cause PostBack(buttons, radio buttons, dropdowns etc), you will need separate event handlers for each control which will have separate logic, since you wouldnt be able to easily identify which control caused the postBack in `PageLoad` event.

In your case with just a button, it looks fine to me to have the code in `Page_Load` with IsPostBack check.

But it is always advised to have Button Click event logic in Click Event Handler itself. That way you don't need to have IsPostBack check. Also code will look clean.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillControls();
        if (IsPostBack) //Will work. But can get executed for postback caused by any other control
        {
            SaveToDB();
            Response.Redirect("URL");
        }            
    }

    protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Assurance that this code will execute only for PostBack caused by Button.
        SaveToDB(); 
        Response.Redirect("URL");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can but it is recommended to use click event for clean code 
if you dont use event and you can do this with

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
   //do something
}
```

bu if you have multiple buttons you will add a condition for each button

```
 if (IsPostBack)
 {
         string target = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
         if (target == "send")
         {
           //do something
         }
         if (target == "update")
         {
             //do something
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

page_load is a part of page life cycle you cannot exclude its execution you can only add checking for IsPostBack

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//Add Your Page Load Code Here
}
```